# Find limit of the function

Tags: calculus

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac { \sqrt {x+bx^2}-\sqrt x}{bx^{3/2}}$$

I tried taking x common and all but it doesn't work.Are there are any shortcuts for finding the answer?Any help is greatly appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: Note:  I reformatted your question pretty heavily.  Please check to make sure I didn't introduce any errors.  For example, I changed it from a two sided limit to a one sided limit, because $\sqrt x$ is undefined if $x<0$.  Is that what you intended?

Comment: It's correct thanks

Answer (score 1):

First of all $b$  cannot be zero.

By multiplying both numerator and denominator by $\sqrt{x+bx^2}+\sqrt{x}$

the function becomes:

> $$\frac{(\sqrt{x+bx^2}+\sqrt{x})(\sqrt{x+bx^2}-\sqrt{x})}{(\sqrt{x+bx^2}+\sqrt{x})bx^{3/2}}=\frac{bx^2}{(\sqrt{x+bx^2}+\sqrt{x})bx^{3/2}}$$ $$=\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x+bx^2}+\sqrt{x}}=\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x(bx+1)}+\sqrt{x}}=\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}(\sqrt{1+bx}+1)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+bx}+1} \to \frac{1}{2}$$ as $x \to 0^+$

Comment: I apologise for this but can you make it easy for me?

Comment: how to make it easy?

Comment: @AbhijithDileepKumar ok now?

Comment: I keep getting 0 when I take terms common from numerator and denominator

Comment: @AbhijithDileepKumar..  you must take $\sqrt{x}$ as a common factor in the denominator because $\sqrt{x+bx^2}=\sqrt{x} \sqrt{bx+1}$

Comment: taking ✓x common i get ✓1+bx-1/bx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65381/discussion-between-abhijith-dileep-kumar-and-marios-gretsas).

Comment: @AbhijithDileepKumar see my answer again ..in the denominator you have a plus sign after multiplying with the expression i mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Multiply by $\dfrac{\sqrt{x+bx^2}+\sqrt x}{\sqrt{x+bx^2}+\sqrt x}$. The appropriate $x^\alpha$-s should go away afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\sqrt{x+bx^2}-\sqrt{x}}{bx^{3/2}}
&=\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\sqrt{1+bx}-1}{bx}\\
&=\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\sqrt{1+bx}-1}{bx}\frac{bx}{\left(\sqrt{1+bx}-1\right)\left(\sqrt{1+bx}+1\right)}\\
&=\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac1{\sqrt{1+bx}+1}\\
&=\frac12
\end{align}
$$